# Add application insights to stateless service fabric app

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet) for starting to use application insights in a .net core application I deploy to service fabric.

My code is really simple

```
public FailedAuthorise(StatelessServiceContext context, IConfigManager config)
        : base(context)
{
    _worker = new Worker<PaymentFailedAuthorise>(config, FailedAuthoriseHandlerFactory.Create, "FailedAuthorise", "FailedAuthoriseError");
}

    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _worker.RunAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Being the worker just a generic class that reads from some queues and processes the messages

But if I was to follow that document I would need to install some nuget packages (which actually are giving me problems to find and/or install, for instance no access to the *using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric;* or will need to change the instrumentation key on a configuration file modification on the pipeline) and start using "hosting" classes that I don't really need in my solution.

Is not a simple way of just adding application insights to what used to be a worker role in the cloud services with no need of the hosting bit?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it's impossible. If you know azure web app or azure function, in the azure portal, there is an blade named application insights, you can just click it and do a very simple ui operation to add application insights. But for service fabric, no such options. So the only way maybe following that doc. But I need confirmation from the app insights team, and will update you if any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/) and create your own custom telemetry like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    public MyService()
    {
        telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        telemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey = "[Your Key Here]";
    }

    public FailedAuthorise(StatelessServiceContext context, IConfigManager config)
            : base(context)
    {
        _worker = new Worker<PaymentFailedAuthorise>(config, FailedAuthoriseHandlerFactory.Create, "FailedAuthorise", "FailedAuthoriseError");
    }

    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Worker started");
        await _worker.RunAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

There are several things you can track, like [exceptions, traces, events, metrics and requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) but if you are not using Asp.Net Core you will have to manually send those events as opposed to having some middleware sending the telemetry to App Insigths.

If your service calls other services you can add [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native) to automatically track communication to other services.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate AI with my service as well, has this guidance changed for 2022?I see the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native package we have FabricTelemetryInitializerExtension.CreateFabricTelemetryInitializer()